# How to query realtime database with AngularFire?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

how to check a specific data in realtime database as well as it checks in firestore ?

```
this.afs.collection('collection', ref => ref.where('data', "==", date
    )).snapshotChanges(.subscribe(res => {
```

I've try

```
this.database.list('collection', ref => ref.where
```

but, "Property 'where' does not exist on type 'Reference'."

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out the AngularFire documentation on [querying lists in the realtime database](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/compat/rtdb/querying-lists.md), and the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering Realtime Database data in JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) which show that querying is done with:

```
this.database.list('collection', ref => ref.orderByChild("data").equalTo(date))
```

Comment: The link above is broken. The new link for querying lists in the rtdb is [this one](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/compat/rtdb/querying-lists.md)